# What abilities do the Infinity Stones share?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, infinity-stones

Not to be mistaken with [this post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/194434/what-powers-does-each-infinity-stone-impart). But in *Avengers: Infinity War*,

> Thanos made Banner's 'Hulk Buster' armor pass through him before trapping it in the rocks.

This closely resembles Vision's ability to pass through objects yet it was not for Thanos had not the Mind Stone. Out of curiosity, I ask if stones in the MCU have shared abilities as others in addition to this one.

Comment: With its reality-bending ability, I would say that the Reality Stone can do many things that the other Stones can do. Actually, I am wondering why the other Stones are needed, when one can just transform reality...

Comment: Ah but reality is a subjective notion. For example, how it was only until thanos left knowhere that the effects of the reality stone wore off. Even the dark elves needed access to the rest of the universe to change reality for everybody.

Comment: Is reality subjective?

Comment: Of course- although some may argue otherwise. It's a rather strong philosophical debate. For example, the only consciousness you are 100% sure of is yourself- so how do you know the people around you are really conscious. Additionally, does the universe around you exist when you are not looking; if so, who pulls the strings to occurrences around you? And, if not, how do you know for sure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The reason Vision could phase was not because of the mind-stone. His body is made entirely of Vibranium, and he can adjust his density at will. He can turn his density so low that he can phase through things. I know this does not make a lot of sense in terms of how physics actually works, but think of it as him vibrating his molecules just perfect a la Flash.
- When Thanos phases Banner+HB into a rock, he has the entire gauntlet(literally) at his disposal. There are numerous ways he could fuse their powers to achieve it. He could use the space stone to teleport banner into the rock,  he could use the reality stone to blend him into it. Both are equally probable. Both of them can have their powers boosted by the power stone, making it very easily possible.

In essence, Visions powers and Banners fate are not correlated.They were the manifestation of entirely different things.

The infinity stones do not inherently have secondary powers.

But the wielder could potentially use the stones original power to great effect with a dash of creativity and understanding of the stones power.

This takes us to some grey areas. For example, the wielder of the Reality Stone could make some person *think* they were in space, without physically teleporting them. Does that mean the Reality Stone could recreate the power of the Space Stone? No.

Now potentially, one could use the Mind Stone to make a person *think* they were in space. But is it really *recreating* the power of the Space or Reality Stone? No.

Comment: “he can adjust his density at will” — if not from the Mind Stone, then where does that ability come from?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It was designed and built by Ultron. He himself touts the flexibility and capabilities of Vibranium. Remember, Ultron intended to use that shell/body for himself. 
The mind stone enables the AI part of JARVIS become a full consciousness.

Outside of all this, IMHO, MCU has handled Vision rather terribly. They never really give him any time to develop as a character, nor do they talk about his abilities.
They have not dealt with his phasing powers at all. Nor did they do anything with his beam capability.

Comment: sure, I just don't think we've seen Vibranium phase before, even in Wakanda. Quite the opposite! But yup, maybe Ultron figured out how to make it do that. The MCU has been super-vague about Vision's powers, but given they're making a series of movies years apart, it probably makes sense not to tie themselves down too much.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I think Vision got added to the picture much later, and they were already at Civil war by that point. They just didn't have any runway to build him up. Vibranium is essentially duesexmachinium.

Comment: what do you mean by secondary powers? And if they aren't there, how does the wielder use non-existent powers to a great effect?

Comment: @yolo -  That line did not work out the way I had intended it to. I have rephrased it.

Comment: So to sum up everything- you'd say that that *although it isn't shown anywhere*, the stones can recreate each others' ability depending on the wielder's imagination?

Comment: @yolo No, they can't. I am saying that their powers can be used in various ways depending upon the wielders understanding of the powers. For example, suppose you're wielding the space stone, and some guy starts shooting at you. You could teleport the guy, you could teleport yourself, or you could teleport the guys bullets back at him. Depends on how well the user understands the stone. This especially applies to the Reality and Mind stone which have ridiculous  powers.